# Auto Resize a frame layout with children on recyclerview scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-framelayout

In my app i'm having a framelayout with many children like textviews and imageview here i want a collapsing toolbar like effect however i am unable to decide how can i achieve that while also auto resizing the children as per the scroll i already tried using a collapsing toolbar but the size of children wasn't adjusted properly as per scroll:

Here is what i'm trying to achieve:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBnrQEyGNfk

and guide or suggestions in this will be really appreciated!

Comment: Try it with motion layout https://medium.com/@jossypaul/motionlayout-simplest-way-to-create-beautiful-animations-in-android-9935db529e75